# Removing old semaphores systemV

Tags: c++, linux, semaphore

Essentially I would like for when my program on starts up to perform something along the lines of

```
set IPCS_S = ipcs -s | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $USERNAME | cut -f2 -d" "

for id in $IPCS_S; do
  ipcrm -s $id;
done
```

I want this to ensure that I am not going to open up a left over semaphores(semaphores that were left open after an abnormal termination).

Is there a way to do this with native C++ code? Or is my best bet to call the external shell script?

Comment: What is your question? Is there something wrong with the code that you posted?

Comment: @Kenster sorry I updated my question with an actual question

Comment: You can do the same from C++, but it's not going to be nearly as concise

Comment: @Cameron can you elaborate?

Comment: Anything that can be done with a shell can be done with a `system()` call. May not be the best solution, though. It's one of those big, fat guns that are hard to keep from backfiring...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Save this file as "removeipc.sh" and then "chmod 777 removeipc.sh",

```
#!/bin/bash

ME=`whoami`

IPCS_S=`ipcs -s | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $ME | cut -f2 -d" "`
IPCS_M=`ipcs -m | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $ME | cut -f2 -d" "`
IPCS_Q=`ipcs -q | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $ME | cut -f2 -d" "`


for id in $IPCS_M; do   echo $id   ipcrm -m $id; done

for id in $IPCS_S; do   echo $id   ipcrm -s $id; done

for id in $IPCS_Q; do   echo $id   ipcrm -q $id; done
```